# Camera position at runtime

Tags: webvr, aframe

I'm playing with a very basic a-frame scene.
I'm looking for info to get camera position at runtime.
Should I use a Component and three.js code?

How could I do it?

Comment: I've RTFM. But I don't find where to start. When I say "at runtime", I mean each time the camera is moving.

Comment: I meant what *code* have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you provide an example? A link to codepen would work http://codepen.io/team/mozvr/

Comment: To get camera position:
<pre>
document.querySelector('[camera]').getAttribute('position')
</pre>

Answer (score 1):

First, grab the camera entity (https://aframe.io/docs/core/entity.html#Retrieving-an-Entity). The camera entity will have the `camera` component attached as an HTML attribute.

`document.querySelector('[camera]')` or `document.querySelector('a-scene').camera.el`

Then use `getAttribute` to grab the position. This will return an {X, Y, Z} object.

`document.querySelector('[camera]').getAttribute('position')`

To be notified of every time the camera updates its position, we can use the `componentchanged` event (https://aframe.io/docs/core/entity.html#Listening-for-Component-Changes):

```js
document.querySelector('[camera]').addEventListener('componentchanged', function (evt) {
  if (evt.detail.name === 'position') {
    console.log('Camera position went from', evt.detail.oldData, 'to', evt.detail.newData);
  }
});
```

Comment: `evt.name` stays undefined :-(

Comment: Fixed, it should be `evt.detail.name`.

Comment: `evt.detail.name` is still undefined.
F.Y.I., `console.log(JSON.stringify(evt))` displays:
`{"isTrusted":false}`

Answer (score 0):

I have finally adopted this solution:

```
<script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent('acceleration', {
        tick: function() {
            var altitude = (this.el.getAttribute('position').z);
        }
    })
</script>
<a-scene>
    <a-entity position="0 0 150">
        <a-entity id="myCamera" camera acceleration look-controls keyboard-controls></a-entity>
    </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

My last problem is I don't get absolute coordinates of camera, but thoses relative to the initiale camera position.